# Wordpress убрать стили из шапки

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как убрать стили из шапки сайта на Wordpress?

Стили, которые нужно убрать имеют class "options-output" и title "dynamic-css"

Возможно эти стили появились после установки плагина "Redux Framework", но не факт.

На сайте стоят два плагина: Redux Framework, Advanced Custom Fields.

[image: Wordpress - инлайновые стили с классом "options-output" в шапке сайта]

Comment: Нужно смотреть тему. В вордпрессе. Так сложно сказать.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="twentynineteen-style-css" href="wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/style.css?ver=1.3" type="text/css" media="all">

add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {

        global $wp_styles;

        echo '<pre>' . print_r ( $wp_styles->queue, true ) . '</pre>';

    }, 9999 );

Array
(
    [0] => admin-bar
    [1] => query-monitor
    [2] => wp-block-library
    [3] => wp-block-library-theme
    [4] => twentynineteen-style  <<--------------------
    [5] => twentynineteen-print-style
)

add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {

    wp_dequeue_style ( 'twentynineteen-style' );
    wp_deregister_style ( 'twentynineteen-style' );

}, 9999 );
```

Comment: Эти стили добавляются плагином redux, и я не могу удалить их вашим способом.

Вот мой массив:
Array
(
    [0] => wp-block-library
    [1] => kztt-style
    [2] => kztt-main-style
    [3] => redux-google-fonts-kztt
)

Удаление redux-google-fonts-kztt не помогло.

Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить все стили с префиксом kztt.

Answer (score 0):

В файле настроек Redux Framework (по умолчанию он называется sample-config.php), в $args = array() найти пункт 'output_tag' и значегние заменить на false.